# Keras batch normalization discrepancy?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation, batch-normalization

I have just noticed that there is a significant discrepancy in the model performance between the training and inference phase in Keras.
I trained a U-Net segmentation model with batch normalization layers. The segmentation accuracy based on Dice metrics reaches to something like 0.92. However, when I apply the same data set on the same model with the exact same weights in the inference phase (model.predict), the segmentation accuracy dropped even 5 to 6 percent.
I googled it a lot and I found it would be related to the way that batch normalization layer works during the training and inference phase to update the moving average and variance in mini batches.
However, still, I have not found a solution to solve this problem. I tried with even binary cross entropy loss function but it did not help. Also lowered the momentum value in the batch norm. layer and it was not effective.
Anyone know how can we get the same results in prediction (inference) phase?

Comment: There is not enough detail here to answer, I don't think its a batch normalization problem, maybe its just overfitting. Please add all details of experiments.

Comment: Francois Chollet (keras creator) addressed how to use pretrained batch normalisation layers in inference mode in this thread https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9965#issuecomment-382857348. Howeve i agree with previous commenters you didn't provide enough information to conclude this was the issue